# Column chart: how to show all labels on horizontal axis

Tags: google-visualization

I've been trying to show all labels on the horizonal axis of my chart, but I haven't been able to do that!

I tried using **hAxis.showTextEvery=1** but does not work

(see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).

[image]

Basically, **I would like to also show numbers "5", "7" and "9" that are currently missing in the above chart.**

Here the JavaScript code, thanks a lot.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
 function drawChart1(){
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
     {
        "cols":[
            {"id":"","label":"ratings","type":"number"},
            {"id":"","label":"# of movies","type":"number"}],
            "rows":[
                {"c":[{"v":9},{"v":26}]},
                {"c":[{"v":8},{"v":64}]},
                {"c":[{"v":10},{"v":5}]},
                {"c":[{"v":7},{"v":50}]},
                {"c":[{"v":6},{"v":38}]},
                {"c":[{"v":5},{"v":10}]},
                {"c":[{"v":2},{"v":1}]},
                {"c":[{"v":4},{"v":1}]}
            ]});

     var options = {
        "title":"Rating distribution",
        "vAxis":{"title":"# of movies","minValue":0},
        "hAxis":{"title":"Ratings","maxValue":10},"legend":"none","is3D":true,"width":800,"height":400,"colors":["red"]
     };
     var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_movies_per_rating'));chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
```

**UPDATE:**
this is the solution I developed, following the answer below (thanks again!).
http://jsfiddle.net/mdt86/x8dafm9u/104/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1); 
function drawChart1(){ 
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable( 
     {"cols": 
        [{"id":"","label":"ratings","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"# of movies","type":"number"}], 
             "rows":
             [{"c":[{"v":"0"},{"v":0}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 1"},{"v":0}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 2"},{"v":1}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 3"},{"v":0}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 4"},{"v":1}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 5"},{"v":10}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 6"},{"v":38}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 7"},{"v":50}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 8"},{"v":64}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 9"},{"v":26}]},
             {"c":[{"v":" 10"},{"v":5}]}
             ]
        }
 ); 

 var options = 
    {"title":"Rating distribution",
    "vAxis":{"title":"# of movies","minValue":0},
    "hAxis":{"title":"Ratings","maxValue":10},
    "legend":"none",
    "is3D":true,
    "width":800,
    "height":400,
    "colors":["CC0000"]};
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_movies_per_rating'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
 } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you not missing a `showTextEvery:1` in your UPDATE code under hAxis? (as @Jeremy Faller's answer has)

Comment: As commented below, no, for me step 4, i.e. showTextEvery:1 was not needed. See my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdt86/x8dafm9u/104/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is related to the continuous versus discrete subtleties in [`ColumnChart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart). Basically, you have continuous values for labels on your `hAxis`, and the `showTextEvery` only works for discrete ones. To fix this, I would do the following:

1. Have all your missing ratings inserted into the chart (ie, if there are no values at rating '3', insert a zero).
2. Order the ratings in the chart. (Google charts could sort this for you, but it's likely easier to just order them.)
3. Change the ratings to `{"id":"","label":"ratings","type":"string"},`
4. Use the showTextEvery:1 in the options

Below is some code that demonstrates this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
{
  "cols":[
    {"id":"","label":"ratings","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"# of movies","type":"number"}],
  "rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":'10'},{"v":5}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'9'}, {"v":26}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'8'}, {"v":64}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'7'}, {"v":50}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'6'}, {"v":38}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'5'}, {"v":10}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'4'}, {"v":1}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'3'}, {"v":0}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'2'}, {"v":1}]},
    {"c":[{"v":'1'}, {"v":0}]},
  ]});

var options = {
  "title":"Rating distribution",
  "vAxis":{"title":"# of movies","minValue":0},
  "hAxis":{"title":"Ratings",showTextEvery:1},
  "legend":"none",
  "width":800,"height":400,"colors":["red"]
};
```

Comment: I know the documentation for showTextEvery says that it works only for a discrete hAxis, but it works fine for me for a continuous (Date) hAxis for me, here: http://www.sealevel.info/co2.html

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Jeremy's solution, another approach is to keep using continuous values on the hAxis, but specify the number of gridlines you want, which should be the same as the number of labels you want.  If you want 10 labels, 1 through 10, this should work:

```
hAxis: { gridlines: { count: 10 } }
```

Comment: This shows ten labels, but with decimal values, not 0-1-2-3...-10, that are:
2.8
3.6
4.4
5.2
6.0
6.8
7.6
8.4
9.2
10.0

Thanks anyway!

Comment: In this case, you'll need to also set the viewWindow.min and .max, probably to 1 and 10.  If you want to include 0 and 10, then the gridlines.count would be 11.