# Google chart not showing all x-axis labels

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets

I'd like to have each label show. It's also not using the full width of the window, which is weird. Any idea how to fix these? Here's the option code:

```
var options = {
'title':'Experience Points',
                     'width':'927',
                     'height':'510',
'chartArea': {'left': '50','width':'927' },
legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2 },
hAxis: {showTextEvery: 0},
hAxis: {slantedText:'true'},
hAxis: {slantedTextAngle: '90'},
isStacked: true
};
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Your `hAxis` options are malformed; they should all be part of a single `hAxis` option, otherwise each one is overwriting the one before.  Also, `hAxis.showTextEvery` has a minimum value of `1`, and the `hAxis.slantedText` and `hAxis.slantedTextAngle` values should not be quoted: `hAxis: {showTextEvery: 0, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 90}`.  If those don't fix the problem, update your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can test it.

Comment: Thanks @asgallant it fixed it! Any idea how to make the bars go all the way across the chart so that they're more spaced out?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I used the following:
`hAxis: {showTextEvery: 1, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 90, viewWindow:{max:33}}`
hAxis.viewWindow.max specifies the maximum amount of hAxis entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column chart: how to show all labels on horizontal axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742651/column-chart-how-to-show-all-labels-on-horizontal-axis)