# Show all labels in hAxis google chart bar

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, google-visualization

I am learning how use the Google Charts API,  to be more specific [Material cloumn charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#creating-material-column-charts).
I want to show all labels in hAxis, for example (1,2,3,4,5 [...]), but my chart shows them in the format (5,10,15, [...]).
I have tried the suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675953/google-chart-not-showing-all-x-axis-labels), but without success.

This is my chart currently: [image: this]

And this is my code:

```
desenharGrafico(data: Array<any>) {

var rows: Array<any> = [];

for (var item of data) {
  var rua = item.rua;
  var valor = item.valor;
  var valorCortado = item.valorCortado;
  var objeto = { c: [{ v: rua }, { v: valor }, { v: valorCortado }] };
  rows.push(objeto);
}

var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable({
  cols: [
    { id: '', label: 'Rua', type: 'number' },
    { id: '', label: 'Faturado', type: 'number' },
    { id: '', label: 'Corte', type: 'number' }
  ],
  rows: rows
});

var options =
  {
    title: "Período: " + this.data1 + ' á ' + this.data2,
    hAxis: { slantedText: true, showTextEvery: 1 },
    legend: "none",

  };
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('cortes-rua'));
chart.draw(chartData, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Comment: Exists alternative solution ?

Comment: It worked .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many options that are simply not supported by *Material* charts,
including `slantedText` & `showTextEvery`
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

an alternative solution is to use `'string'` values for the x-axis

this will result in a *Discrete* axis, vs. *Continuous*

with enough room, a *Discrete* axis will display all labels...