# Google Charts show all labels

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to display a horizontal bar chart on a page. I am using the google charts library. The issue I am having is that some labels are being missed off. Is there a way of forcing all labels to display?

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population', ],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000],
    ['New York City2, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles2, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago2, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston2, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia2, PA', 1526000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: {
      width: '50%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**Demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e16qrz00/)**

You will notice in the above code that there are 11 labels/values. All values are displayed but every other label is missing. I would like all labels to be displayed.

[Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742651/column-chart-how-to-show-all-labels-on-horizontal-axis) << This question has been asked but it concerns a different type of chart with a different data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set specific size and placement of the `chartArea`

to allow room for each axis label and title

along with the chart title, legend, etc...

see following example, added `backgroundColor` to highlight each area

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawBasic,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawBasic() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population', ],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000],
    ['New York City2, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles2, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago2, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston2, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia2, PA', 1526000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'cyan',
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',

    // total size of chart
    height: 600,
    width: 900,

    // adjust size of chart area
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'magenta',

      // allow 70px for hAxis title and ticks
      height: 480,

      // allow 200px for vAxis title and ticks
      left: 200,

      // allow 50px for chart title
      top: 50,

      // allow 200px for legend on right
      width: 500
    },

    colors: ['yellow'],
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```