# Remove column key from google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, column-chart

I am using column google chart. I need to change the direction of column key which is highlighted into red circle in image below.

[image]

So what I want to achieve

1. Is there any property so I can change the direction like top, bottom or left side so it displayed properly (Revenue) as of now it display (R...).
2. If direction cannot be changed, then how can I remove this from charts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is the property called *chartArea*

You can control how much area from top, right, bottom or left to be shown. 
**Here chart area is area of only the chart, excluding label, legend or any other value other than the chart itself**.  You can reduce the chart area so that label/legend can come completely.

```
chartArea: {
    height: '500',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 30,
    bottom: 0
},
```

Regarding the legend positioning, you can change place of legend using

```
 legend: {
              position: 'left'
          }
```

To remove legends altogether use

```
legend:{position: 'none'}
```

**See below snippet or this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/_pirateX/z7e6me4v//) to see how it works.**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Submitter', 'Count'],
    ['Service', 168],
    ['NAME 1', 42],
    ['NAME 2', 36],
    ['NAME 3', 35],
    ['NAME 4', 34],
    ['NAME 5', 30],
    ['NAME 6', 24],
    ['NAME 7', 21],
    ['NAME 8', 18]
  ]);
  var options = {
    pieSliceText: 'percentage',
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    height: '500',
    chartArea: {
      height: '500',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 30,
      bottom: 0
    },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart6_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart6_div"></div>
```

Comment: this answer works, here's [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37275107/5090771)